# Better way to get all attributes from a Moose class as a hash

Tags: perl, moose

I want to get all attributes back from a class as a hash.
Is there any better way to do it than this ?
Ideally(?) I would like to be able to say something like:

```
my $hash = \%{ Diag->new( {range =>1, code => 'AB'} ) };
```

But will settle for:

```
my $d = Diag->new( {range =>1, code => 'AB'} );
my $hash = $d->hash;

package Diag;
use Moose;

my @attrs = qw/range code severity source message/;

has 'range'    => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Int' );
has 'code'     => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'String' );
has 'severity' => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Int' );
has 'source'   => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'String' );
has 'message'  => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'String' );

sub hash {
    my $self = shift;
    my $hash = {};
    for (@attrs) {
        $hash->{$_} = $self->$_;
    }
    return $hash;
}

no Moose;
1;
```

**EDIT** Hash with string output for pack/unpack:

```
# Combining this attribute and the record_format would be great.
# if $self->record->format worked that would be cool.
has 'record' => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'HashRef',
    default => sub {
        {  
            foo => 'A5',
            foo2 => 'A16',
        }
);

sub record_format 
{
    my $self = shift;
    my @fields = qw( foo foo2 );

    return _build_format_string($self->record, \@fields);
}

sub _build_format_string {
    return join '', map { $_[1]->{$_} } @{ $_[2] };
}
```

**EDIT2**
I found that if I created an Attribute Trait I could make this a little nicer. This way the hash order is with the attribute and only one format method is needed.

```
package Order;
use Moose::Role;

  has order => (
      is        => 'ro',
      isa       => 'ArrayRef',
      predicate => 'has_order',
  );

Moose::Util::meta_attribute_alias('Order');
1;

package Record;
use Moose;

has 'record' => (
    traits  => [qw/Order/],
    is      => 'ro',
    isa     => 'HashRef',
    default => sub {
        {
            foo  => 'A5',
            foo2 => 'A16',
        },
        ;
    },
    order => [qw(foo foo2)]
);

sub format {
    my ( $self, $attr ) = @_;
    my $fields = $self->meta->get_attribute($attr)->order();
    return join '', map { $self->{$attr}{$_} } @$fields;
}

1;


my $r = Record->new();
print $r->format("record");
Outputs: A5A16
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would much rather pack that into a method, but your "ideal" case is almost there

```
my $data = { %{ Diag->new( {range =>1, code => 'AB'} ) } };
```

The `%{...}` returns a (*key,value,...*) list so you want `{}` to make a hashref out of it, not `\` (which curiously turns it back into an object).

But really, that should be tucked away in a method

```
my $data = Diag->new(...)->get_data;

package Diag;
...
sub get_data { return { %{$_[0]} } };
...
1;
```

---

For purely presentational purposes – to print them out – consider using a module, so you don't have to worry about (or know) which attributes have what reference as a value. I use [Data::Dump](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/Data-Dump-1.23/lib/Data/Dump.pm) for conciseness of its output

```
my $obj = Diag->new(...);

say $obj->stringify();                           # whole object serialized

say for $obj->stringify('attr1', 'attr1', ...);  # serialized values for each

package Diag;
...
use Data::Dump qw(pp);
...
sub stringify {
    my $self = shift;
    return map { pp $self->{$_} } @_  if @_;
    return { pp %$self } }
}
```

If native OO is used and not `Moo`/`Moose` also overload `""` for `say $obj;` use

```
use overload q("") => sub { return shift->stringify() }
```

In `Moo` and `Moose` the stringification of object under `""` (implied in prints as well) is provided.

---

*By further clarifications the code below doesn't address the actual problem. I'll edit but I am leaving this for now as it was deemed generally useful.*

It has come up in comments and question edit that a part of the intent is to be able to retrieve values for attribute(s) as well, and packed.  The added code does that, but as there is explicit dereferencing a check with `ref` should be added so to correctly retrieve all values, from either of arrayref,  hashref, or string/number. For example

```
sub record_format {
    my ($self, @attrs) = @_;
    @attrs = qw(attr1 attr2 ...) if not @attrs;  # default list
    my $packed;
    foreach my $attr (@attrs) {
        my $val = $self->{$attr};
        my $rv = ref $val;
        if    (not $rv)        { $packed .= $val }
        elsif ($rv eq 'HASH')  { $packed .= join '', values %$val }
        elsif ($rv eq 'ARRAY') { $packed .= join '', @$val }   
    }
    return $packed;
}
```

This packs values of the passed attributes or of the listed defaults.

The desired `$self->record->format` can't work nicely since `$self->record` doesn't return an object so you can't string another method call. You *can* write an accessor but if you made it return an object under any circumstances that would likely be a surprising behavior, thus not good design.

Comment: This method could typically also be called `TO_JSON`, which is what modules like `JSON` look for when serializing objects.

Comment: @simbabque Good point, thank you -- but there is no guarantee that it will actually be a _valid_ JSON?

Comment: Thanks @zdim just what I was looking for. Also related, Is it possible if you have an attribute that contains a hash, can you add a custom toString() that formats the values and returns a string of them ? So can call like $data->myHash->toString();

Comment: @williamt Glad to hear that :).  Now, as for that string -- first, you mean like `attr => { ... }` (so, a hashref)? The interface you show wouldn't work, since `$data` is a hashref (not object, if you mean `$data` from this answer), and then `$data->myHash` is a hashref -- so you can't call a method on it.  But, you can write another method for that. Or, `get_data` method can take arguments, a list of attribute names for example, for which it will return serialized values.

Comment: @williamt you cannot have a method call on a hash. Your myHash would have to be an object.

Comment: @williamt Then precisely how you stringify/serialize can indeed be in another method, which can either be internal (so you only offer `get_data` interface for all such needs), or a normal method which can then be used on its own as well. But then that could end up a little messy, with overlapping methods -- think through this nicely so that you end up with an intuitive and clean design.

Comment: @zdim thanks. This is what I came up with. See any problems or know of a more elegant way? code posted above because of formatting.

Comment: @williamt Right, some such ... will get back in a bit and comment/edit.  (One thing, `join ''` will stick them together -- you want space I guess, or return a list?)

Comment: @zdim no I want them together. building a format string for unpack. thanks!

Comment: @williamt Added some code, not realizing that you have a very specific purpose with this (to pack them for `unpack`) ... hopefully it's still useful. I'd suggest to mark that last segment with **EDIT** and add a note on the purpose of it.

Comment: @williamt The ability to do `say $obj;` and have it stringified and printed nicely.  Btw, come to think of it, how are you going to unpack those glued values? If it's `unpack`, it would need to know the lengths of packed stirngs.

Comment: @zdim I understand what stringify is. I just didn't see what made it available to use. When I ran it I got a no method found error. The hash values provide the formatting. So when ran I can use it like this: \@data = unpack "a1A2A10A10A6A4A1A3A2A1a23a23A8", $record;

Comment: @williamt ugh -- the sub was meant to be called `stringify` and not "serialize" ... :( ... fixed, thank you!  As for `unpack` -- but how do you know those lengths?  Where do they come from?  You aren't planning on _knowing_ and typing them in?  (That can be returned by the sub, as well; one string with the `unpack` template, built by `length` on keys, and another with packed values. Unless you do have something else in mind.)

Comment: @zdim The keys could be used for something else later. These attribute hashes are all known and predefined.$obj->stringify('attr1') would just return the values all joined together to be used as a template to unpack. Its a shame that I can't make $obj->attr1->stringify work.

Comment: @williamt Wait, what can you not make work? Doesn't `$obj->record_format(@attr);` do that? (In `record_format` instead of `@fields=...` you take them from `@_` of course.).  I still don't see how you intend to unpack.  You return packed values from `record_format`, but `unpack` also needs their lengths, `unpack "a1a4a3", $str;` where `$str = pack "a1a4a3", qw(v1 val2 vv3);`.  (You may well have a good system in mind, I just don't see it.)

Comment: @williamt  I mistyped a length above, should be `"a2a4a3"`. (And you don't have to `pack` them first of course, `unpack "a2a4", 'v1val2';` is fine.)

Comment: @zdim `@attr` needs to be stored somewhere so I stuck it in the record_format sub. It could be an attribute I suppose. It's really only needed to pull the values out in an ordered fashion. `@data = unpack "a2a4", 'v1val2';` works just fine. I'm not sure what other lengths you are talking about. The lengths are included in the hash values `a1 A6` etc. These are just fixed length text records. Am I missing something?

Comment: @williamt I'm asking -- how do you know at runtime that it's "a2a4"? Hang on ... do you need this always for all attributes (or all values of one attribute's hashref)? So it's a hard-coded string somewhere? Or you'll form it when you form an object?  It's still better to form it dynamically, even perhaps as another attribute, at construction.

Comment: @williamt Come to think of it, if this is all fixed it can all be done in constructor.

Comment: @zdim The object is responsible for parsing a file with several different record types. The idea is to have a hash attribute that contains the field names and unpack format for each record type. so record one might be `{id => a1, desc => A24, number => a10}` while record2 might be `{id => a1, addr => A64, zip => a5}`. The format string for each record never changes but is tied to the attribute. I'm not sure how it would be done in the constructor. I certainly could just store a pre-formatted string like a1A64a5, but I think its a lot more descriptive and easier to maintain this way.

Comment: @williamt OK, I see; rather thought out and involved.  I had just updated the answer with something that seemed suitable but I now understand that it probably isn't. If it's off-point or useless let me know and I'll roll it back.

Comment: @williamt What I just added seems completely _not_ what you need; I now get those `@fields` etc.  Let me know whether it's still of some use so I leave it, or to roll it back (and edit some).

Comment: @zdim Its not really suitable to my situation but I like it. :) The problem with using values %$val, is that the values will be returned in a "random" order which is not what you want if you are expecting a certain format of record.

Comment: @williamt  Right, I see that after your explanation of what it's about. Also, you do know that it's a hashref and you know exactly which attritube (and you want to supply names of _fields_ that that attribute collects, etc). So it's just off ... I'll consider whether to leave it, edit, or remove and edit.

Comment: @zdim Thanks a lot for your help on this. See my edit about an Attribute Trait. What do you think?

Comment: @williamt  Interesting, and may well be for a job for a role ... I'll look nicely tomorrow (and will certainly edit my answer).